# Is there a way to check if a specific program is running (using Python)?

Tags: python

How can i check if a specific python file is running through another python file?
for example in python file1 there will be a condition:

```
if file.IsRunning:
```

i have tried to do:

```
__author__ = 'Cyber-01'
import psutil

def IsRunning(name):
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            if len(p.cmdline())>1:
                if name in p.cmdline()[1]:
                    return True
        except:
            None
    return False

if running("server.py"):
    print "yes"
```

but it always returns yes no matter

Comment: To clarify your question: By 'throw'. do you mean 'via'?

Comment: I think they meant "through"

Comment: This seems to work for me. Although I would recommend replacing the `None` line with `pass`. Is it possible there is a zombie `server.py` process?

Comment: how can i identify a zombie process?

Answer (score 4):

First-attempt:

```
import psutil

def running(name):
    name_list = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])
            if name in pinfo['name']:
                return True
            else:
                pass
        except:
            return False
```

**EDIT**

A solution more in line with the OP's original post:

```
def running3(program, scriptname):
    for pid in psutil.pids(): # Iterates over all process-ID's found by psutil,  
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid) # Requests the process information corresponding to each process-ID, the output wil look (for example) like this: <psutil.Process(pid=5269, name='Python') at 4320652312>
            if program in p.name(): # checks if the value of the program-variable that was used to call the function matches the name field of the plutil.Process(pid) output (see one line above). So it basically calls <psutil.Process(pid=5269, name='Python') at 4320652312>.name() which is --> 'Python'
                """Check the output of p.name() on your system. For some systems it might print just the program (e.g. Safari or Python) on others it might also print the extensions (e.g. Safari.app or Python.py)."""
                for arg in p.cmdline(): # p.cmdline() echo's the exact command line via which p was called. So it resembles <psutil.Process(pid=5269, name='Python') at 4320652312>.cmdline() which results in (for example): ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', 'Start.py'], it then iterates over is splitting the arguments. So in the example you will get 2 results: 1 = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python' and 2 = 'Start.py'. It will check if the given script name is in any of these.. if so, the function will return True.
                    if scriptname in str(arg):  
                        return True
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
        except:
            continue

if running3('Python', 'server.py'):
    print("Yes, the specified script is running!")
else:
    print("Nope, can't find the damn process..")
```

As to why the OP's code wasn't working:

I can see a couple of wrongs in the code. First of all, the indentation of `return False` places it outside the for-loop, thereby creating a situation in which the function will always return `False`.

Furthermore the `psutil.Process.cmdline()` returns the command that was used to execute the current process. When `psutil.Process.cmdline(1)` is called it is supposed to return the command line via which the process of PID 1 was called. However, this seems to throw up a lot of permission errors. This, in turn, causes `if len(p.cmdline())>1` to fail almost all of the time, raising the exception and thus returning `None` in the OP's code.

**Second EDIT (tested the two solutions for optimal performance)**

- Code 1 (using `psutil.process_iter()`): 100 loops, best of 3: 4.37 msec per loop
- Code 2 (using `psutil.Process(pid).name()`): 1000 loops, best of 3: 945 usec per loop
- **Conclusion: the 2nd code seems to be your best bet!**

Comment: In the OP code, they are searching for the second item on the command line (the first parameter). `name` from the process doesn't contain that information.

Comment: Well, might be a good thing depending on what you want.. My option leaves less space for confusion. Since if you have a process like `/somefolder/Safari/some_related_but_independent_sub_process` and you are checking if `Safari` is running, the OP's code will answer yes, while mine will answer no. It all depends on what you want.. How specific you want to get.

Comment: why isn't it good for a large scale project and what was wrong with my code?

Comment: i want to be able to find the process-c:\server.py

Comment: Because creating a list and appending each item is quite memory intensive (if you are talking really large scale, that will slow you down). Having another look at your code though.. I think your indentation on `return False` might be faulty, since your function will always return False..

Comment: PS: If you execute my code like `running("server.py")` it should print yes. (if server.py is running of course..)

Comment: Edited my code with some further explanation and an additional working code snippet that stays closer to your own efforts.

Comment: See if my final edits answer you question fully. If so, you might mark it as solved :)

Comment: i have tried to use your code, i swap the return True/False in print True/False, but now it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Which is only logical since the function returns either True or False, if you want it to print any output you could either call the function like `if running2("server.py"): print("yes")` or simply make the function return a string instead of `True` and call the function from within a print statement

Comment: i changed all the return to print,so it does need to print

Comment: It depends on how you made the statement, because print(True) will not print anything.. print("True") will since that is a string.. if you want, paste the exact code you are using now in an edit to your original question so I can see what's going wrong

Comment: Ah yes and I see now by your original question that you appear to be using python2 while my code snippet is python3.. shouldn't be a problem but he print statement would need a different syntax

Comment: Otherwise, if you could create a [trinket](https://trinket.io/welcome) I could have a look at your code and see what's possibly at fault.

Comment: this is my code https://trinket.io/python/fedc7d4d66 it prints always "no"

Comment: Fixed it for you: https://trinket.io/python/af527e3297. You actually need the running3 function. I'll add that in my answer as well. Please read all the comments I posted next to your original code.

Comment: now when i tried the trinket code it printed nothing, when i used the code you posted here(runnin3) it always returnes "can't find proces..."

Comment: Add the `print p.name()` statement after `p = psutil.Process(pid)` so can see what is actually going on..

Comment: If you need even more feedback add `print p.cmdline()` as well. Try to make sure you understand what is going on.. it could well be that on your system you need to execute running3 like `if running3('python.exe', 'server.py'):` or something else still.. the only way to know for sure is to check the output of `p.name()` and `p.cmdline()` for every `p`.

Comment: I updated my latest Trinket with a 4th option that adds a lot of print statements... again, try to understand your code so you know what is going on.

Comment: when i print the names it appears to me as pycharm.exe/python.exe, not by the files name

Comment: So, then your command should be `running4('python.exe', 'server.py')` or `running4('pycharm.exe', 'server.py')`, depending on how you run your script. Also, you might need to replace `server.py` with the corresponding output of `p.cmdline()` where `p.name()` = `python.exe` or `pycharm.exe`

Comment: This really shouldn't be so hard.. are you completely new to coding? If so, I think it would help you a lot if you'd take some beginner tutorials so you learn to understand what is happening.. if you do, you'll see that the things you are running into aren't really errors but misunderstandings on your part. Without being able to really look inside your computer people will be unable to answer your questions in an exact manner, but they can give you the base code which is easy to adapt to your situation if you understand what is going on. Hence the up-votes this post has gathered..

Comment: actually i am not new in programming... when i print the names the name server doesnwt appear so i think that the problem is not in the arguments,if you will attach an explanation on what p.name()/cmdline() etc. means it will be very helpful

Comment: I am having a hard time to understand what it is that you are unable to understand? If you want to know the values of p.name()/p.cmdline() just add a few print statements and have a look? Anyhow.. I edited my answer once more, adding an explaining comment after almost every meaningful line..

Comment: To improve the universality of the code I have also added a statement to iterate over the cmd arguments. This way, when you call your script with multiple arguments e.g. `python -some_arguments myscript.py` instead of `python myscript.py` it will also work (it did not do so before).

Comment: all the changes are not helpfull because when i print the process' names it doesn't return anything whith "server" in it

Comment: Server most likely isn't mentioned in p.namr()

Comment: erver most likely is not mentioned in `p.name()` but in `p.cmdline. ()`

Comment: Again, I really think you should take some introduction tutorials to Python and how to read the documentation of it's modules. If you are still looking for `server` in `p.name` it means that most likely you still do not understand the basic concepts of the code in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is:

```
import psutil
print("Roblox" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter()))
```